# Bind domain name to hosting CentOS

Tags: centos-6, bind

I own "YouPlus.biz" and I own hosting at 192.169.218.8 (goddady VSP)

I have been trying to Bind youplus.biz to 192.169.218.8 but have had no luck.

have tried:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-bind-dns-server-on-centos-6

No dice

Any help is great

Comment: You don't need bind to do that. Go to your registar's webpage, set an A record pointing at your server.

Comment: You should have to look at this [godaddy](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names?countrysite=in) howto page

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing between bind (verb - mapping your domain to your host/ip) with Bind (name of Linux DNS service). All you need is to log into domain control panel and create A record of domain that point to your server IP address. Keep in mind that "domain.com" and "www.domain.com" is 2 seperate domain, so you will need one A record for each or one A record for "domain.com" then make reference from "www.domain.com" to "domain.com" (CNAME record).

I bet that this is not familiar with you, so you should ask a technical guy do it for you.

Comment: Or make A names for both.